# PHP Error Logging in XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, xampp, error-logging, error-log

I am doing PHP development using XAMPP. I have found a file called "error_log" in the "logs" directory of my XAMPP files that seems to record every error that occurs on the server. What I'd like to be able to do is set up various error logs that only record error that occur in specific php files. Can anyone advise me on how to set this up.

Answer (score 2):

You can't specify it. You can just set the error level in php.ini and add seperate log files for per project.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm still a little unclear on how to implement this as I'm a bit of a php noob. Is there a php.ini file in each project folder? And how do I designate a new log file so the server know to write errors to it?

Comment: php.ini file should be in your xampp setup folder. i dont know windows exactly but it should be near the other configuration files. you will set php.ini once and all projects use it. but you need to create vhost and define separate error log for different document roots. see http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ExampleVhosts